# How to programatically render several Angular 7 components from a string?

Tags: angular

I currently have an Angular 7 application serving as the frontend to a headless Wordpress installation. Most Wordpress posts contain predefined Angular components in their body and I'm running into trouble rendering the post body after getting it from an API call.

I have successfully gotten this working with the JIT compiler (by dynamically compiling a new component and module from scratch), but have only found out since building with the --prod flag that this doesn't work with the AOT compiler.

Example markup coming from Wordpress would look like the following:

```
let apiData = '<p>A paragraph and <app-component-one></app-component-one>.</p>
<app-component-two someInput="test"></app-component-two>
<p>Another paragraph</p>';
```

Now what I'd like to have is another component that can take this string and properly render the markup and components inside of it. Something like:

```
<app-dynamic-content [content]="apiData"></app-dynamic-content>
```

Is something like this even possible with AOT enabled?

Comment: No, this is not possible with AOT enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<div [innerHTML]="apiData"></div>` if not works for components try directives.

Comment: This doesn't cause the components to render unfortunately.

Comment: Try to make Directives except components ? Still dont know are it will work